# Installing rpy2 on python 2.7 on macOS

Tags: macos, python-2.7, clang, openmp, rpy2

I have python version 2.7.10 on macOS High Sierra and would like to install rpy2.

When I do *sudo pip install rpy2*

I get the error message:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-Nwbha3/rpy2/
```

I have already upgraded setuptools (version 39.0.1).

I also downloaded the older version rpy2-2.7.0.tar.gz and tried installing it with *sudo pip install rpy2-2.7.0.tar.gz*. I then get the following error message:

```
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-O0cu4E-build/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-haDUA3-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-O0cu4E-build/
```

If somebody has the answer to my installation problem, it would be greatly appreciate it.
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of pip are you on?

Comment: The `clang` that ships with Mac does not support `openmp` which is what the `-fopenmp` flag is for.

Comment: My version of pip is 9.0.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `clang` that ships with Mac does not support `openmp` which is what the `-fopenmp` flag is for. You'll likely need a version of clang that supports openmp.

One possible solution would be to get the full llvm/clang build with openmp support. With homebrew you can do:

```
brew install llvm    # clang/llvm
brew install libomp  # OpenMP support
```

And then try installing `rpy2` again with newly installed version of clang.

As an example, the current version is `6.0.0` so you would run

```
CC=/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/6.0.0/bin/clang pip install rpy2
```

Comment: Hopefully, binary packages will soon be available so that installation works out of the box again. Here's the related issue: https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/403/cannot-pip-install-rpy2-with-latest-r-340

Comment: Note that this procedure links to `libomp` as installed by Homebrew. If you want to link to the lib shipped with the official R framework, see the BItBucket issue.

Comment: bitbucket link is dead